# profileimage undefined error in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

upon POST I do below code

```
if(req.files.profileimage){

        var profileImageOriginalName = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
        var profileImageName = req.files.profileimage.name;
        var profileImageMime = req.files.profileimage.mimeType;
        var profileImagePath = req.files.profileimage.path;
        var profileImageExt = req.files.profileimage.extension;
        var profileImageSize = req.files.profileimage.size;
    } else {
        //set a default image
        var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
    }
```

But I got an error saying profileimage is undefined. That's so strange.

Answer (score 0):

You need middleware to handle the multipart form data and split it into the files portion of the req object. I'm assuming you're using express.

Multer is a node mod than can do this for you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Is there anything in req.files? What does your route look like? What does your request look like? Check the response body and check if the file content is in there.

Comment: I tried to console, but it got refresh / redirect when I click on 'register'. How to debug?

Comment: I'd recommend adding console.logs to your server code for debugging and using curl to post a file to the path so you can isolate the problem.